# ¿ Cómo pasar un array de arrays de PHP a Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

tengo este array:

```
$consultaEspecificacionesResultado
```

El cual si le hago un print_r me muestra esto:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_especificacion] => 1 [0] => 1 [id_projecte] => 1 [1] => 1 [nombre_especificacion] => espe1 [2] => espe1 [dificultad] => facil [3] => facil [descripcion] => Crear boton [4] => Crear boton [tiempo] => 01:00:00 [5] => 01:00:00 [id_usuario] => 1 [6] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id_especificacion] => 2 [0] => 2 [id_projecte] => 1 [1] => 1 [nombre_especificacion] => esp2 [2] => esp2 [dificultad] => facil [3] => facil [descripcion] => hola [4] => hola [tiempo] => 02:00:00 [5] => 02:00:00 [id_usuario] => 1 [6] => 1 ) )
```

Es decir, tengo un array que en la posición 0 hay X cosas y en la posición 1 otras, estoy tratando de pasar ese array a Javascript para despues usarlo en una función, lo he intentado hacer asi:

```
var array_especificaciones= <?php echo json_encode($consultaEspecificacionesResultado);?>;
divEspecificacionesPB(array_especificaciones);
```

Ahora tengo una funcion llamada `divEspecificacionesPB(array_especificaciones)` y quiero mostrar cada uno de los valores del array anterior.
Gracias.

Comment: Te aparece algún error?

Comment: No, de todas las maneras que lo he intentado no me sale nada, ni error ni nada, simplemente no funciona.

Comment: Qué parte es la que no funciona?

Comment: No se como puedo printar un array de arrya en javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Si es un array valido entonces puedes ponerlo de la siguiente manera en un script

```
var array = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>);
```

> [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) En PHP Retorna la representación JSON del valor dado, es decir: convierte datos en formato JSON
>
> [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) En Javascript analiza una cadena de texto como JSON, transformando opcionalmente  el valor producido por el análisis, es decir: convierte una cadena json en datos manipulables